# Full C++ LibTorch API on Moblie [Android]

Tags: android, c++, mobile, pytorch, libtorch

I'm trying to compile a programme which uses LibTorch for android.
But the libraries built by `script/build_android.sh` in the pytorch repo, contain only the `torch.jit` Module. I need the `torch.nn` Module.

Is it possible to access the full C++ LibTorch API ? If so how can I build it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that by setting NO_API to OFF and BUILD_MOBILE_AUTOGRAD to ON in the root CMake file, your can build the api and thus torch.nn.